# Azure function iLogger isEnabled is not picking up host.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to avoid executing the log.debug when the debug level is not enabled in the Azure function. When I execute the below code, the control goes within the IF block. Please explain why this is getting executed irrespective of the config in host.json file.

I tried creating another object using ILogger logger2 but still, it was the same.

```
[FunctionName("Function3")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        log.LogCritical("*****From Function3******");


        log.LogTrace("LogTrace");
        if (log.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
        {
            //Control should not come inside this as the debug level is not enabled 

            log.LogDebug("Debug message inside debug level");//Not printed as expected.
            log.LogInformation("Inside Debug level"); //Not printed as expected
            log.LogError("LogError Inside Debug level"); //Printed because of the setting in host.json
        }
        log.LogDebug("LogDebug");
        log.LogInformation("LogInformation Blue");
        log.LogWarning("LogWarning Yellow");
        log.LogError("LogError Red");
        log.LogCritical("LogCritical White");

        return new OkObjectResult("Okay!");
    }
```

Host.JSON

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
      "Function.Function3.User": "Error",
      "Function.PaymentFeeder.User": "Warning",
      "Function": "Warning"

    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update:
Using Visual Studio 2022 and targeting.Net 6
Including the screenshot
[image: Output Message]

Packages referred:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.30" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="4.5.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
```

Thanks

Comment: In host.json, it must be `logLevel`,  and `default` , notice the first char in lower case.

Comment: Need not define for Function.Function3.User, just `Function.Function3` is sufficient. I am not getting that behavior you are observing.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks for your input, I have updated the logLevel and default but it did not make any difference. I will attach the screenshot and the packages referred in the function. I am using VS2022 and TargetFramework is .Net 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We check the same which you are using in your **host.json** and **functions**.

We follow the same, here the workaround:

If you want to avoid executing the **log.debug** when the debug level is not enabled follow below:

If we want to avoid for specific function you can mention like this  **"Function.Function1.User": "Error"** which is for specific function to use specific logs. Example here For Funciton1 we enabled the Error logs so here it ***won't enter*** into if block **if (log.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))**

[image]

Here is the workaround for using **Debug level** log in **Function1**

Here we mention the **Function1** should ***use*** the **Debug** log so It will enter into if block **if (log.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))**

[image]

Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) for more information on **LogLevel** configuration

**UPDATE:**

Using **Error** `loglevel` for Fucntion1

[image]

Using **Debug** `logLevel` for Function1

[image]

Comment: so, with or without .User the level is read by Az func runtime, is it ?

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem is, the control goes inside the if block which you highlighted even when I set the log level to Error.

Comment: I tried with both "Function.Function3": "Error" and "Function.Function3.User": "Error". It still goes into the IF block

Comment: Check your host.json file which you used. as per @AnandSowmithiran said you have to make sure it will be *logLevel* and *default*

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT Yes, I have updated the host.config already but still the outcome was the same. I have added the screenshot showing the change and the log that got generated in it.

Comment: @HobbyLobbyVS, I am not sure why your side is behaving differently. Please make sure you have to restart your function app after changing the **host.json** file. Please check i have updated my answer with a gif for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I created a new function and it is working as expected. The problem seems to occur only when I add "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" in the local.settings.json file. Once I add that key, it ignores the settings in the host file log level setting. If I remove that, it works as explained. I think you can replicate the scenario if we replace the setting. 
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "ReplaceWithKey"
  }
}